# Custom System Notification, Similar to the Volume Notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, notifications

How would you go about creating a popup system notification in OS X, just like the volume notification.  Xcode also shows one of these notifications when it completes a build.

You can see what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB04z.png).

I would prefer to use a built in API call (which I would assume exists somewhere) over building it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many open source projects that implement HUD notification views. Two notable projects are [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD). Either of them should be suitable for your needs.

**EDIT for OS X**: There are no open source projects that I know of that could be used for this on OS X. However, it would not be difficult to make this yourself. Here are the key details that you need and should get you up and running:

1. Create a custom borderless, transparent `NSWindow` as shown [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html).
2. Create a custom frame view that draws the rounded transparent black HUD background. You can use `NSBezierPath` to create a round rectangle drawing path.
3. Add subviews to the window's content view (e.g. image view to display an icon and a text field to show text underneath it).
4. You can use the animator proxy to fade this window in and out. e.g. `[[window animator] setAlphaValue:1.f]`.

Comment: I knew of both projects previously.  Unfortunately, they're both for iOS and not for OS X.  I've edited the post to make that more clear.

Comment: Edited my post to add some details on how you could make it yourself.

Comment: And to answer your question about a built-in API call, there is none.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I had the general idea already.  Now how would I position it in the same place as the system notifications?

Comment: If you just took a screenshot of your screen while the volume HUD was displayed you could easily figure out the size and position and set the frame of your custom window accordingly. That and set your `NSWindow`'s level to `NSFloatingWindowLevel`.

Comment: That doesn't allow me to position it in the same relative location on all screen sizes and resolutions though.

Comment: Why not? You could calculate the relative position for any resolution by using a percentage of the margin relative to each edge of the screen.

Comment: That only works as long as it is calculated off of a percentage and not a constant added or subtracted to a percentage.

Comment: Either way, it needs to be determined empirically by testing various resolutions. There's no built in API to calculate the position nor to display the HUD itself.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there's some fork of MBProgressHUD with macOS in mind:
https://github.com/Foxnolds/MBProgressHUD-OSX